# Ramda: access input object's properties inside R.ifElse() function call

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have this existing function:

```
  const inferProcessingError = R.ifElse(
    R.propEq('conversionJobStatus', 3),
    R.always('Last Process failed with error; please contact DevOps'),
    R.always(null)
  );
```

which is called like this:

```
const msg = inferProcessingError(jobStruct || {});
```

with this jobStruct:

```
{"id":9,"mediaGroupId":1000000,"conversionJobStatus":3,
  "errorDetails": {
     "Cause": {
        "errorMessage": "MediaConvert Job Failed with ERROR status: ERROR Video codec [indeo4] is not a supported input video codec",
     },
     "Error": "Error",
   }
}
```

and I need to create an error message string which includes the data from the `Cause.errorMessage` element.

This would be dead simple with a native JavaScript function, but I'm learning Ramda and want to just modify the existing code to include in the error message.

An `R.prop('Cause')['errorMessage']` could work except that I can't figure out how to reference the jobStruct that was passed in to the `inferProcessingError` statement.

I can see that the `R.ifElse` and subsequent Ramda functions are able to get that reference, but when I embed an `R.prop('Cause')` in the error message string, it resolves to a function and not the value of the `Cause` element because it seems to be waiting for the data structure.

So...how do I gain access to the jobStruct reference? (`arguments` is not defined here).

**UPDATE:** 
I can get this to work by referencing the original jobStruct as in `R.Prop('ErrorDetails', jobStruct)['Cause']['errorMessage']` but that seems rather kludgy to me...

BUT if the call to `inferProcessingError` is actually inside a `map` statement and references an element in a larger structure, then the map index is not available to reference the data structure for the `R.prop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [`pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) and [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) methods to achieve this "the ramda way".

Begin by using ramda's `path()` function to extract the nested `errorMessage` value from the input `jobStruct` object. Next, enclose that in a `pipe()` that transforms the extracted message into a string formatted with a custom error prefix:

```
const incCount = R.ifElse(
    R.propEq('conversionJobStatus', 3),
    
    /* Evaluate this pipe if the error case is satisfied */
    R.pipe(
        /* Path to extract message from input object */
        R.path(["errorDetails", "Cause", "errorMessage"]), 
        /* Prefix string to extracted error message */
        R.concat('Custom error prefix:')),
    
    R.always('')
);

incCount({"id":9,"mediaGroupId":1000000,"conversionJobStatus":3,
  "errorDetails": {
     "Cause": {
        "errorMessage": "MediaConvert Job Failed with ERROR etc etc",
     },
     "Error": "Error",
   }
});
```

Here's a [working example](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20incCount%20%3D%20R.ifElse%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.propEq%28%27conversionJobStatus%27%2C%203%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.path%28%5B%22errorDetails%22%2C%20%22Cause%22%2C%20%22errorMessage%22%5D%29%2C%20R.concat%28%27Custom%20error%20prefix%3A%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.always%28%27%27%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AincCount%28%7B%22id%22%3A9%2C%22mediaGroupId%22%3A1000000%2C%22conversionJobStatus%22%3A3%2C%0A%20%20%22errorDetails%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22Cause%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22errorMessage%22%3A%20%22MediaConvert%20Job%20Failed%20with%20ERROR%20status%3A%20ERROR%20Video%20codec%20%5Bindeo4%5D%20is%20not%20a%20supported%20input%20video%20codec%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22Error%22%3A%20%22Error%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%29%3B) - hope that helps!

#### Update

Thanks to @customcommander for the suggestion to use [`concat`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat) for the string prefix, as well as returning an empty string value for the second branch

Comment: Hmm...with R.pipe, wouldn't that be a suffix as it reads left-to-right? I would think R.compose would make it a prefix.

Comment: I was just referring to the resulting string have a custom prefix formatted to it

Comment: Two suggestions: 1- for better composition the second branch should return an empty value of the same type, i.e. an empty string. 2- you can replace the lambda in your first branch with `R.concat('Custom error prefix: ')`